# nginx variable for logging that has the rewrite destination

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have 301 hits going to the access log, but I am looking for a way to include the destination, or "Location" as it is in the http response header, to the access log. I have looked at all the variables, but none seem to be that. Thanks.

Comment: $upstream_http_location http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_http_

Comment: I don't see that variable mentioned on the linked page, and I tried that and it doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks, though!